# Chrome not sharing the cookie between the subdomains

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

When I use the value  `domain:".example.com"` in my cookie, I expect it to support the subdomains **xyz.example.com, abc.example.com** etc

This works fine on mozilla firefox but does not seem to work on google chrome! On chrome it creates a new cookie for **xyz.example.com** which fails to serve the purpose.

Is this a known issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You might find this answer to be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23086139/4266776

Comment: @RezaKarami Hey man whoever/wherever you are god bless you :) That was it!

Answer (score 20):

I know this is bit of a far fetch, but not all domains can have cookies set to them. https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat list is honored by Chrome, Firefox and Safari to mention the most popular browsers.

Assuming the above **example.com** would be **s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com** very weird thing could be observed. The Set-Cookie header would be present in the response data, but browser's wouldn't display it in the network traffic inspector nor it would have any effect. Because the data **is** there, it can be observed via eg. curl.

Ref. [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.3)

Comment: You sir are an absolute legend, I have been struggling with this all day using azurewebsites.net domain name. I simply configured my CNAME's to point to custom domain names and hey presto it started working!!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Care to guess how I found that out? :-D

Comment: I haven't a clue??

Comment: Spent half a day trying to get my Azure site to accept a cookie and realizing it never will.

Comment: Haha! well we have that in common!

Comment: I did a search specifically for cookie domain .azurewebsites.net just in case this is what was happening. Ah well, I've been arguing for CNAMES for our dev environments anyway, guess I win!