# I can't set a cookie for parent domain from subdomain

Tags: networking

I'm using express and using ngrok to test my server so I have a URL like `a846d0979b95.ngrok.io`. In express I'm trying to set a cookie so that the domain property is "**.ngrok.io**" and not "**a846d0979b95.ngrok.io**" to set the cookie on the domain and not on the subdomain.

```js
response.cookie('test-cookie', '1234', {
    domain: '.ngrok.io'
})
```

Although on chrome dev tools the cookie is not accepted. Chrome gives the error
**This Set-Cookie was blocked because its Domain attribute is invalid with regards to the current host URL**

[image]

#### Note:

I can set the cookies for `a846d0979b95.ngrok.io` with the default domain "a846d0979b95.ngrok.io" with no problem

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52475993/529282 ngrok.io is indeed defined in https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome not sharing the cookie between the subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419074/chrome-not-sharing-the-cookie-between-the-subdomains)

Comment: @Martheen I can set cookies on ngrok no problem. those are accepted and stay there. what I can't do is set a cookie 's property to `.ngrok.io`. the request URL is <some-hash>.ngrok.io and it returns a cookie whose domain is supposed to be .ngrok.io ( the parent domain) that's what fails.

Comment: @masonCherry Public Suffix List says: "Avoid privacy-damaging "supercookies" being set for high-level domain name suffixes". I think we can't set `Domain=.ngrok.io`

Comment: Try using localhost.run

Comment: @RenanCoelho what is that?

Comment: What? Localhost.run? It is a service like Ngrok I'm using as an alternative. It is working with cookies when you set `Domain=.xxx`

Comment: I wish i saw this a couple hours ago :) .ngrok.io just have to keep cookies on subdomain and it works fine.