# Unable to set Cookie from javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set cookie from client side.

when I set cookie on webapp https://360.thesolarlabs.com/ for the domain `.thesolarlabs.com`
like `'arka=test;domain=.thesolarlabs.com;path=/'`, cookie is set.

But when I do the same on webapp https://arka360-production-development.azurewebsites.net/

like `'arka=test;domain=.azurewebsites.net;path=/'` for the domain `.azurewebsites.net`, cookie is NOT set.

What is the reason ?

EDIT: Found the reason. There is a list of domain names that you cannot create sub domain cookies against.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/360645/cannot-set-a-subdomain-friendly-cookie.html
[Chrome not sharing the cookie between the subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42419074/chrome-not-sharing-the-cookie-between-the-subdomains/52475993#52475993)

Answer (score 0):

**Cookies cannot be set to a different domain than your current origin**.\

Let's say you're generating a cookie form `auth.domain_1.com` you can only set the cookie to `.domain_1.com` but you cannot set cookie from `auth.domain_1.com` to `.domain_2.com`.

Comment: But I am setting cookie from  https://arka360-production-development.azurewebsites.net/ on domain  .azurewebsotes.net.  Here domain and origin are same right?